# Convergence of recursive sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a non-negative sequence defined as: 
\begin{equation}
x_{n + 1}^{2} = 1 + x_{n} + {1 \over 6}\,\sin\left(x_{n}^{2}\right)\,,\qquad
x_{0} = 1. 
\end{equation}
How to show that $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ converges ?.

Comment: *Maybe* works: prove that $f(x)=\sqrt(1+x+\sin(x^2)/6)$ is contractive ($|f'|<c<1$) in some interval.

Answer (score 2):

Three steps:

1. Use induction to show that $x_n\ge1$.
2. Use induction to show that $x_n\le2$.
3. Show that $x_n$ is increasing. The easiest way is to show that the derivative of $\sqrt{1+x+\sin(x^2)/6}$ is positive on the interval $[1,2]$ and that $x_2>x_1$.